# Using a foreach loop to change values in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have encountered an interesting quark in Java.

This code segment will execute as expected (change all values inside the array to 0):

```
int[][] test = {{4, 2, 6}, { 7, 4, 10 }, { 3, 4, 1 } };
for (int[] current : test) {
    current[0] = 0;
    current[1] = 0;
    current[2] = 0;
}
```

However this will not:

```
int[][] test = {{4, 2, 6}, { 7, 4, 10 }, { 3, 4, 1 } };
for (int[] current : test) {
    for (int num : current) {
        num = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I understand why the second code segment does not work. I'm wondering why the first segment works. Thanks. I am not looking for "this will work" responses, I want to know what distinguishes the first segment from the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your change to a `local` variable only. It does not impact the array you are traversing.

`for-each` loop is just a synthetic sugar for loop with `iterator`.

Comment: Thanks, but then why does the first code segment work?

Comment: Because you use the array explicitly.

Comment: Two dimensional array is a one-dimensional array of references to one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Iterator<Integer> num = current.iterator(); num.hasNext(); ) {
    num = 0;
}
```

This is what happens when foreach is expanded. What you have to understand is that in your first snippet, the Iterator iterates over a single-dimensional array named "current", which is passed by reference. So any changes in current will reflected on  "temp". However, ints are passed by value, and that is the reason why in your second snippet, the changes made in "num" are not reflected in "current". So you are simply changing the value of some other variable not related to your original array. Try printing the following for better understanding.

```
    int[][] test1 = {{4, 2, 6}, { 7, 4, 10 }, { 3, 4, 1 } };
    for (int[] current : test1) {
        for (int num : current) {
            System.out.println(num);
            num = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice and very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library method [Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int%29) to set the same value for single-dimensional array. Use it, this way your code will be clean and fast.

```
int[][] test = {{4, 2, 6}, { 7, 4, 10 }, { 3, 4, 1 } };
for (int[] current : test)
    Arrays.fill(current, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
int[][] test = {{4, 2, 6}, { 7, 4, 10 }, { 3, 4, 1 } };
for (int[] current : test)
    for (int i = 0; i < current.length; i++)
        current[i] = 0;
```