# Why this piece of Java code produces this output <null, null, null>?

Tags: java

A Java class with the following main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    final int n = 3;
    String[] array = new String[n];

    for (String string : array) {
        string = "OK";
    }

    for (String string : array) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

produces the output "null, null, null,". Eclipse IDE suggests me that "The value of the local variable ref is not used". Why?

N.B.: I know that I have to iterate the array using this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<n ;i++)
    array[i] = "OK";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720200/why-doesnt-this-for-each-loop-work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364706/using-a-foreach-loop-to-change-values-in-a-2d-array

Comment: And a couple hundred more.

Comment: Yes: It's a duplicate.

Comment: It's equal to:
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String s = array[i];
    s = "OK";
}